# Usage of the "history" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

What is the purpose of [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)? Isn't there any other tag that would, even partially, be used instead of [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)? For example, the history of a word is its etymology; if I am asking for the etymology, I use [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), not [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).

Answer (score 2):

I think my question [What is the historic process for converting vulgar words into simply rude words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17773/what-is-the-historic-process-for-converting-vulgar-words-into-simply-rude-words) fits a tag of history. The question is asking about more than the history of a specific word but rather an entire group or class of words. The language-evolution tag was apt so I also chose it.

I am not strongly attached to any of the tags and would be happy with any decisions so long as the tags themselves get a good description of what should be in that category. If, for instance, the etymology tag's wiki told me that it was most appropriate for the type of question I had asked I would have done so.

Comment: The excerpt for the _etymology_ tag is the following: "Etymology is the study of the history of words and their origins."

Comment: I guess I interpreted "words" as "individual words" not "words and groups of words." My bad.