# Should [history] be a synonym for [etymology]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just retagged (well, I don't have retag privileges, so queued an edit for voting) a question that had the [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag to [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) but then I noticed there are 70-odd other such questions.

Should that be a synonym, then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the questions tagged [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), I see a number of questions that should be tagged [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) (probably most of them). However, I don't think all of the [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) questions belong in etymology, for example:

- [Have grammar rules changed through the history of the English language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/have-grammar-rules-changed-through-the-history-of-the-english-language)
- [Why did English become a universal language and when?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5831/why-did-english-become-a-universal-language-and-when)
- [What's the origin of Pig Latin?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/whats-the-origin-of-pig-latin)
- [Is there a historical trend towards shorter sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3602/is-there-a-historical-trend-towards-shorter-sentences)

These questions are about historical things, but they aren't about words.

Incidentally, I actually disagree with the response in [Usage of the "history" tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/usage-of-the-history-tag), that looking at the evolution/origin of a class of words is not etymology; I think it is.

In any case, I guess the question we should ask is if the [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag is useful enough to stand on its own. Clearly, people are using the tag instead of [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), so there is widespread confusion about the tag. That said, I would **not** want to see the questions I have listed above to be tagged [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology); that would be flat-out wrong. If [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) became a synonym for [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), I fear we might end up with questions like the above getting that tag.

Comment: Excellent examples. Yes, the two tags are distinct.

Comment: +1, yeah they are 2 different things. People get confused but I'd be against any proposal about removing any of those two.

Comment: My concern is that if the majority of history-tagged questions should be etymology-tagged, then the tag isn't very useful.  Perhaps we block the tag (there are banned tags, AIUI) instead.

Comment: @Richard Gadsden: I agree about the problem of people misusing the tag, but, for example, the question "Why did English become a universal language and when?" is tagged `usage` and `history`.  I don't think the question would be better off with only the `usage` tag.